# change value of column from list to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna change values of column from list to pandas series

This is my input, in this case values are list

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| [2, 9, 3] | [1, 2] |
| [1, 3] | [2, 4, 5] |

Expected Output, in this case each values are pandas series

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 9 3 | 1 2 |
| 1 3 | 2 4 5 |

Comment: The separator in the desired output is a space?

Comment: It is not a separator, bcz the data is integers, each value in a column should be pandas series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to achieve this,

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A' : [[2,9,3],[1,3]],
    'B' : [[1,2],[2,4,5]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def convert(row):
  row['A'] = pd.Series(row['A'])
  row['B'] = pd.Series(row['B'])
  return row

df = df.apply(convert,axis=1)
```

Comment: you don't need to make a custom function for this, this is not a suitable solution imo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the output from the accepted answer is what you're after, you can simply do the following:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [[2, 9, 3], [1, 3]], "B": [[1, 2], [2, 4, 5]]})
df.apply(pd.Series, axis=0)
```